# undefined method `find_by_login'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

after installing the [simple-private-messages](https://github.com/professionalnerd/simple-private-messages) plugin, i try to send a message but i got undefined method `find_by_login'. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is simply how you find your user record in the database.  find_by_login suggests that in their example, their user model has the login property.  This depends on your model, you may have called this name, username, email, etc.  You can also use the ID such as:

```
frank = User.find(1)
```

To test the plugin, as long as you have a User in your database, you can do:

```
user = User.last
```